# How to replace null with the default Value in C# dynamic Collection?

Tags: c#, null, type-conversion

I'm having a ObservableCollection of Model MobileList.

In the Collection most of the Values holds the null.

Here I want to Convert the null to the Corresponding DataType.

For Exmaple:

- `String obj = string.Empty;`
- `int obj = new int();`
- `DateTime obj = new DateTime();`

> Note: the Collection is dynamic, I can't check whether the null is
>   belongs to Int or float or bool or anything. Kindly Suggest on
>   Universal Conversion Function to use it in all places. Kindly Consider
>   the Corresponding Model Property DataType, based on the Property we
>   have to change the null to corresponding DataType

```
public class Mobile
{
    private ObservableCollection<MobileModel> _mobileList;
    public ObservableCollection<MobileModel> MobileList
    {
        get { return _mobileList; }
        set { _mobileList = value;}
    }

    public Mobile()
    {
        ObservableCollection<MobileModel> mList = new ObservableCollection<MobileModel>();
        ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo> modList = new ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo>();
        MobileModel mob = new MobileModel();

        modList.Clear();
        mob.Brand = "Apple";
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "iPhone 4", Catagory = "Smart Phone", Year = Convert.ToDateTime("12/18/2011"), Version = null });
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "iPhone 5", Catagory = null, Year = Convert.ToDateTime("07/11/2013"), Version = 1.0 });
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "iPhone 6", Catagory = "Premium Smart Phone", Year = null, Version = 1.0 });
        mob.Model = new ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo>(modList);
        mob.OS = "IOS";
        mList.Add(mob);

        mob = new MobileModel();
        modList.Clear();
        mob.Brand = "Samsung";
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "S4", Catagory = "Smart Phone", Year = Convert.ToDateTime("04/05/2011"), Version = 1.0 });
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "S5", Catagory = "Smart Phone", Year = null, Version = 1.0 });
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "S6", Catagory = "null", Year = Convert.ToDateTime("01/05/2011"), Version = null });
        mob.Model = new ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo>(modList);
        mob.OS = "Android";
        mList.Add(mob);

        mob = new MobileModel();
        modList.Clear();
        mob.Brand = "MicroSoft";
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "Lumina 9900", Catagory = "Phone", Year = null, Version = null });
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "Opera X220", Catagory = "Smart Phone", Year = Convert.ToDateTime("02/04/2013"), Version = null });
        mob.Model = new ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo>(modList);
        mob.OS = "Windows";
        mList.Add(mob);

        mob = new MobileModel();
        modList.Clear();
        mob.Brand = "Sony Ericssion";
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "S4", Catagory = "Smart Phone", Year = Convert.ToDateTime("01/05/2011"), Version = 1.0 });
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "S5", Catagory = "Smart Phone", Year = Convert.ToDateTime("08/05/2013"), Version = 1.0 });
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "S6", Catagory = "Ultra Smart Phone", Year = null, Version = null });
        mob.Model = new ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo>(modList);
        mob.OS = "Android";
        mList.Add(mob);

        MobileList = new ObservableCollection<MobileModel>(mList);

        MakeDefaultforNull(MobileList);



    }


    public void MakeDefaultforNull(ObservableCollection<MobileModel> Source)
    {

    }

}

public class MobileModel
{
    private string _brand = string.Empty;
    private ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo> _model = new ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo>();
    private string _os = string.Empty;

    public string Brand
    {
        get { return _brand; }
        set { _brand = value; }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo> Model
    {
        get { return _model; }
        set { _model = value; }
    }

    public string OS
    {
        get { return _os; }
        set { _os = value; }
    }
}

public class MobileModelInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Catagory { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Year { get; set; }
    public double? Version { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to handle `null` within the class using `setter` like the following:

```
  public class MobileModel 
    {
        private string _brand = string.Empty;
        private List<MobileModelInfo> _model = new List<MobileModelInfo>();
        private string _os = string.Empty;

        public string Brand
        {
            get { return _brand; }
            set {
                if (value == null) { _brand = String.Empty; } //You know the type of the variable so you can easily set its default value.
                else { _brand = value; } OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: In my Main Project, I'm having more than 100 Properties. So, I Can't able to set the if condition to check the value as null. So, I need a general function to replace the null with the default value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection for getting the data-type of each property and set a default-value. But this is for sure not the cleanest solution.